# Reading and filtering a file into a string

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I need to read the contents of a text file into a string while removing certain lines at the same time. The lines to be removed can be identified with a substring match. I could come up with the following solution, which almost works, the only problem is that the newlines are removed:

```
val fileAsFilteredString = io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.filter(s => !(s contains "filter these")).mkString;
```

How can I keep the newlines?

Comment: I'd suggest `...getLines.filterNot(_ contains "filter these")...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add some parameters to `mkString`:

```
val fileAsFilteredString = io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines
    .filter(s => !(s contains "filter these")).mkString("\n")
```